# Dictionary - how to add condition for specific value of key and value?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, key

```
 my_dict =  {
      "camel": "ok",
      "test_environments": [
        {
          "Branch Coverage": "-",
          "ASIL": "ASIL-D",
          "Test Environment": "APCOM",
          "Test Configuration": "Vehicle",
          "Statement Coverage": "-",
          "Test Status": "36/36(100%)",
          "Type of Code": "handwritten",
          "MC/DC Coverage": "-",
          "Verified SW Units": "APCOM"
        },
          "Branch Coverage": "-",
          "ASIL": "ASIL-B",
          "Test Environment": "AP",
          "Test Configuration": "Per",
          "Statement Coverage": "-",
          "Test Status": "20/20(100%)",
          "Type of Code": "handwritten",
          "MC/DC Coverage": "-",
          "Verified SW Units": "APCOM"
        }
      ]
    }
```

I want to do something like this: if the value of any key is '-' and value of ASIL is ASIL - D, to split 'Branch Coverage' key to two keys and assign them 0. Branch Coverage would become: "Branch Coverage Passed" :"0" and "Branch Coverage Covered" :"0"

I'm trying with this code, but I don't know how to add additional condition that those values become 0 only if ASIL is ASIL - D:

```
for index, _ in enumerate(my_dict['test_environments']):
    for key, values in my_dict['test_environments'][index].items():
        new_key = key.replace(" ", "_").lower()

        if '-' in values:
            value1 = 0
            value2 = 0
            my_dict['test_environments'][index]['branch_coverage' + '_passed'] = value1
            my_dict['test_environments'][index]['branch_coverage' + '_covered'] = value2
```

Comment: Could you please post example input with at least two 'test_environments' and the expected output?  Also clarify exactly what "'if the value of some key is '-' and ..." means. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can use:

**Option 1**: replace old entry by new entry

```
for index, env in enumerate(my_dict['test_environments']):
    if env['ASIL'] == 'ASIL-D':
        data = {}
        for key, val in env.items():
            if env[key] == '-':
                data[f"{key} Passed"] = 0
                data[f"{key} Convered"] = 0
            else:
                data[key] = val
        my_dict['test_environments'][index] = data.copy()

print(my_dict)

# Output
 'test_environments': [{'Branch Coverage Passed': 0,
   'Branch Coverage Convered': 0,
   'ASIL': 'ASIL-D',
   'Test Environment': 'APCOM',
   'Test Configuration': 'Vehicle',
   'Statement Coverage Passed': 0,
   'Statement Coverage Convered': 0,
   'Test Status': '36/36(100%)',
   'Type of Code': 'handwritten',
   'MC/DC Coverage Passed': 0,
   'MC/DC Coverage Convered': 0,
   'Verified SW Units': 'APCOM'}]}
```

**Option 2**: add new values to current entry

```
for env in my_dict['test_environments']:
    if env['ASIL'] == 'ASIL-D':
        data = {}
        for key, val in env.items():
            if env[key] == '-':
                data[f"{key} Passed"] = 0
                data[f"{key} Convered"] = 0
            else:
                data[key] = val
        env.update(data)

print(my_dict)

# Output
{'camel': 'ok',
 'test_environments': [{'Branch Coverage': '-',
   'ASIL': 'ASIL-D',
   'Test Environment': 'APCOM',
   'Test Configuration': 'Vehicle',
   'Statement Coverage': '-',
   'Test Status': '36/36(100%)',
   'Type of Code': 'handwritten',
   'MC/DC Coverage': '-',
   'Verified SW Units': 'APCOM',
   'Branch Coverage Passed': 0,
   'Branch Coverage Convered': 0,
   'Statement Coverage Passed': 0,
   'Statement Coverage Convered': 0,
   'MC/DC Coverage Passed': 0,
   'MC/DC Coverage Convered': 0}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand exactly what you want. If you want to replace '-' by 0, you can loop through like this :

```
my_dict =  {
      "camel": "ok",
      "test_environments": [
        {
          "Branch Coverage": "-",
          "ASIL": "ASIL-D",
          "Test Environment": "APCOM",
          "Test Configuration": "Vehicle",
          "Statement Coverage": "-",
          "Test Status": "36/36(100%)",
          "Type of Code": "handwritten",
          "MC/DC Coverage": "-",
          "Verified SW Units": "APCOM"
        }
      ]
    }

for dic in my_dict['test_environments']:
    for key in dic:
        if dic[key] == '-':
            dic[key] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This does literally what you said you want to happen (I think):

Sample data:

```
my_dict =  {
      "camel": "ok",
      "test_environments": [
        {
          "Branch Coverage": "-",
          "ASIL": "ASIL-D",
          "Test Environment": "APCOM",
          "Test Configuration": "Vehicle",
          "Statement Coverage": "-",
          "Test Status": "36/36(100%)",
          "Type of Code": "handwritten",
          "MC/DC Coverage": "-",
          "Verified SW Units": "APCOM"
        },
        {
          "Branch Coverage": "-",
          "ASIL": "ASIL-B",
          "Test Environment": "AP",
          "Test Configuration": "Per",
          "Statement Coverage": "-",
          "Test Status": "20/20(100%)",
          "Type of Code": "handwritten",
          "MC/DC Coverage": "-",
          "Verified SW Units": "APCOM"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Code:

```
import json  # For printing result.

for test_env in my_dict['test_environments']:
    if(test_env['ASIL'] == 'ASIL-D' and
       any(['-' in value for value in test_env.values()])):
        for key, value in test_env.items():
            if value == '-':
                test_env['branch_coverage' + '_passed'] = 0
                test_env['branch_coverage' + '_covered'] = 0

print('Result:')
print(json.dumps(my_dict, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

Output:

```
Result:
{
    "camel": "ok", 
    "test_environments": [
        {
            "ASIL": "ASIL-D", 
            "Branch Coverage": "-", 
            "MC/DC Coverage": "-", 
            "Statement Coverage": "-", 
            "Test Configuration": "Vehicle", 
            "Test Environment": "APCOM", 
            "Test Status": "36/36(100%)", 
            "Type of Code": "handwritten", 
            "Verified SW Units": "APCOM", 
            "branch_coverage_covered": 0, 
            "branch_coverage_passed": 0
        }, 
        {
            "ASIL": "ASIL-B", 
            "Branch Coverage": "-", 
            "MC/DC Coverage": "-", 
            "Statement Coverage": "-", 
            "Test Configuration": "Per", 
            "Test Environment": "AP", 
            "Test Status": "20/20(100%)", 
            "Type of Code": "handwritten", 
            "Verified SW Units": "APCOM"
        }
    ]
}
```